# Access /dev/tpm0 from Kubernetes pod without privileged mode

Tags: kubernetes, socat, docker-privileged

I am running a Kubernetes Pod for a service that needs to access the `/dev/tpm0` device on the host. This works in privileged mode, however, I want to work unprivileged. Is there a way of establishing a proxy for `/dev/tpm0` under a `/anotherpath` accessible to a specific user that is not root? Something like socat but for devices - or is it possible to configure /dev/tpm0 on the system to be accessible without privileged mode?

Comment: What is that device file?  Why would it be safe for an otherwise-isolated process to access it?

Comment: if you have access yo this host you can modify this path permissions with `chmod`,  it would be best to set a minimum required permissions, but if you like YOLO approach the `chmod -R 777 /dev/tmp0` should do the work (note that this allows everything to anyone!)

Comment: It's not that simple :) I found this to work:
https://github.com/squat/generic-device-plugin

However, the plugin itself runs in privileged mode, so we've only shifted the problem further down. However, the plugin runs under kube-system and can be hidden away by an administrator. The plugin is distroless and uses the Kubernetes device framework. So ultimately it is more legitimate than binding the device myself. I will go with that solution, although it doesn't answer my question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The privileged mode is required by Kubernetes to access devices. There seems to be no workaround.

To avoid custom containers to access the device directly, it is possible to use the device plugin at https://github.com/squat/generic-device-plugin

This plugin will now run in privileged mode under kube-system, however, all other containers can now run unprivileged.